# Compare past dates in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have to write a LINQ statement that finds the number of times an item appears in a database over the past 90 days.  That's easy but they are wanting to see the data in terms of 1-30 days, 31-60 days, and 61-90 days.

What I'm currently doing is creating a model that has the four sets of data, getting a list of  all the unique SKU's, and then finding how many times they appear in the data base.

My problem is the date ranges.  I'm create new DateTime objects and adding NEGATIVE days to them and I'm trying to use that to compare ranges.  I can't figure out how to say something like this:

Edited date is between (-30 days) and (-60 days).

I can't use a SP for this.  There has to be an easier way.  Maybe using a time span and seeing if it falls in that span?  I'm not sure.  I rarely work with dates.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding negative days to a datetime. Also, if they only want the number of times it appears, why do you need sets of data? Just add a .Count() to your LINQ query and directly get the number.

Comment: @Mathieu.  I am adding the.Count() but I wasn't able to get the correct date filter. It was returning 0 because (as I posted below) I was comparing the dates in reverse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime minusThirty = today.AddDays(-30);
DateTime minusSixty = today.AddDays(-60);

// Normally I wouldn't use a query expression for just a single where clause,
// but I assume you want more...
var query = from item in db.Table
            where item.Date >= minusSixty && item.Date < minusThirty
            select item;
```

You *may* want `<=` and `>` instead - you should work that out for yourself. However, you almost certainly want *one* bound to be inclusive and *one* bound to be exclusive, and use those consistently - that way no item will end up in more than one bucket.

Comment: Ah man I'm so dumb.  This is what I had exactly except I was comparing the dates in reverse and that's why I kept getting 0.  *Face palm

Comment: @Chase: Just be glad you're not doing anything more complicated. Date and time arithmetic can get *hard*... http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2010/11/joys-of-datetime-arithmetic.html

Comment: I am glad.  The most I ever work with dates is capturing the date an object is added to the database and/or formatting that date into a string when it is returned.  LOL.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now().AddDays(-30);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now().AddDays(-60);

if (yourDate.Date >= date2.Date && yourDate.Date <= date1.Date)
{
   //DoSomething
}
```

Comment: Don't call `DateTime.Now` twice - you could end up changing date between the two. Basically you want your two dates to be based on the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to write a LINQ query when unsure of your structure.  But to get that date range you can do something like this in code:

```
var difference = laterDate - earlierDate;

if (difference <= TimeSpan.FromDays(60) && difference >= TimeSpan.FromDays(30)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to work for me VB.NET 3.5
returns a list of items in the past 10 minutes ... I'm sure it can be adjusted to meet your needs

```
    ' if online time is greater than 10 minutes ago pickup user                                check onLineTime.Date = now.AddMinutes(-10).Date              check onLineTime.TimeOfDay = now.AddMinutes(-10).TimeOfDay
     Dim rsl = From s In db.tblSessions Where (s.SessionID <> context.Session.SessionID AndAlso s.onLineTime.Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10).Date AndAlso s.onLineTime.TimeOfDay > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10).TimeOfDay)
```

where s.onLineTime is a SQL DATETIME field ie. 2015-02-11 04:49:26.283

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do something like

```
        TimeSpan beginning = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);

        var query = from item in database
                    let difference = DateTime.Now - item.TimeStamp
                    where difference > beginning &&
                          difference < end
                    select item;
```