# Getting All Items Earlier Than Now From DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table which stores tasks to be performed in the future by an MVC system. This is going to be done by a page which will be called periodically to find all tasks that need to be done.

The future tasks are going to be stored with a datetime in them which is the time they should be completed. They will also contain other information which i will use to process the task accordingly. Once a task has been pulled from the DB i will remove it from the db so it cannot be called again.

I am trying to query the db to get all the tasks that have a "dueDateTime" that is before now. and store them in a object list. Something like this:

```
tasksList = db.ScheduledTasks.Where(s => s.date.CompareTo(System.DateTime.UtcNow));
```

This does not work and is more psudo code than anything, but i cant seem to find any resouces online to help me with this. Could someone help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 db.ScheduledTasks.Where(s => s.date < System.DateTime.UtcNow);
```

If you compare with UTC time, the time should be parsed to UTC before saved to db.

Lambda expression do not support compare method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `s.date < DateTime.Now`?  Note there's a caveat with Daylight savings.

Also check out [this SO link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7363278/2779990)